# Ckeditor not displayed after installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ckeditor

After install CKedit dont work. I used the guides - https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor

I've tried everything but it does not work

*config/initializers/assets.rb*

```
`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(ckeditor/config.js)`
```

*config/initializers/assets.rb*

```
//= require ckeditor/init
```

*routes.rb*

```
mount Ckeditor::Engine => '/ckeditor'
```

**ActiveRecord** + **carrierwave**

```
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'mini_magick'

rails generate ckeditor:install --orm=active_record --backend=carrierwave
```

everything tried, but anyway dont work, help

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is simple code try this .No need any gems

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <title>Full page editing with Document Properties plugin</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.11.2/standard-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
  <textarea cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10">
            </textarea>
  </div>
  <script>
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
      fullPage: true,
      extraPlugins: 'docprops',
      // Disable content filtering because if you use full page mode, you probably
      // want to  freely enter any HTML content in source mode without any limitations.
      allowedContent: true,
      height: 320
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice, ty. How change language? And how connect image upload?